# How to parse un delimited txt file with php?

Tags: php, parsing

I have a txt file.. It is a result of GFF file... can any one of you point me how to find a specific string and the value next to it in another column?

Comment: Post some sample data, and you'll probably get a useful answer.

Comment: I can't imagine a file having no delimiters at all. Aren't these files usually delimited by whitespace? I second neokio, please post some sample data.

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What's a "GFF file"?  What does your text file look like?  We can't help you parse something unless we know what it looks like.

Comment: ##source-version exonerate:protein2genome:local 2.2.0
##date 2013-03-25
##type DNA
#
#
# seqname source feature start end score strand frame attributes
#
FTB exonerate:protein2genome:local gene 3 6435 1683 + . gene_id 1 ; sequence genome.pep ; gene_orientation +
FTB exonerate:protein2genome:local cds 3 104 . + . 
FTB exonerate:protein2genome:local exon 3 104 . + . insertions 0 ; deletions 0
FTB exonerate:protein2genome:local splice5 105 106 . + . intron_id 1 ; splice_site "GT"
FTB exonerate:protein2genome:local intron 105 498 . + . intron_id 1

Comment: @BahaaYasin: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17490427/edit) that into the question?  What exactly are you looking for from inside that file?  What problem are you having parsing it?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am assuming your GFF file is according to these [specifications](http://www.sanger.ac.uk/resources/software/gff/spec.html).
In that case you can read the file line by line (and split the columns to get an array) using the following:

```
// Open the file
$file = fopen('your_file.txt', 'r');

// Go over the lines
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);

    // Check if cds is found in one of the parts
    $cds = search('cds', $parts);

    // We found one
    if ($cds !== false) {
        // Get the next value
        $value = $parts[$cds + 1];

        // Do something with it             
    }

}
```

Comment: here is a sample of my data http://bahaa.ca/file.txt I need to get the every word says cds and the value next to it

Comment: I've edited the code to do just that.

Comment: what is search? is this a function?

Comment: It is array_search.... Thank you so much..your code does what I need

Answer (score 0):

You need to read file (usually line by line) to find out what 's inside.

Comment: well, it has white spaces but I have few columns and some other text that don't have any order... I will post a sample

Comment: You can split the line into parts then, by using something like '$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);'. If your columns really don't have any order you can just check each column for the one you need.

Comment: here is a sample of the data http://bahaa.ca/file.txt